# VHDL adder, same word length?

Tags: vhdl, bit

In VHDL i want to add a number of 5 bits and a number of 8 bits.(Unsigned) And how many bits does the output have?

I want my code to answer the questions i just asked. My code currently look like this...

My code is:

```
library ieee;
use ieee-std_logic_1164.all;
entity adder is
port( a : in unsigned (7 downto 0);
         b : in unsigned (4 downto 0); - - Need to convert this to 8 bit right? But how?
         z : out unsigned(7 downto 0)); - - This one must be  8 bits right? Cuz a & b & z must have the same WL. Or am i wrong?

end adder;

archictecture add of adder is 
begin 
z <= a + b;
end archictecture;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In package numeric_std for `function "+" (L, R: UNSIGNED) return UNSIGNED` the length of the longest argument defines the return value length:

```
  function "+" (L, R: UNSIGNED) return UNSIGNED is
    constant SIZE: NATURAL := MAX(L'LENGTH, R'LENGTH);
    variable L01 : UNSIGNED(SIZE-1 downto 0);
    variable R01 : UNSIGNED(SIZE-1 downto 0);
  begin
    if ((L'LENGTH < 1) or (R'LENGTH < 1)) then return NAU;
    end if;
    L01 := TO_01(RESIZE(L, SIZE), 'X');
    if (L01(L01'LEFT)='X') then return L01;
    end if;
    R01 := TO_01(RESIZE(R, SIZE), 'X');
    if (R01(R01'LEFT)='X') then return R01;
    end if;
    return ADD_UNSIGNED(L01, R01, '0');
  end "+";
```

The maximum of the left and right arguments length is `SIZE`, the range of the two arguments is is resized to `SIZE -1 downto 0` as arguments to `ADD_UNSIGNED`.

```
  function ADD_UNSIGNED (L, R: UNSIGNED; C: STD_LOGIC) return UNSIGNED is
    constant L_LEFT: INTEGER := L'LENGTH-1;
    alias XL: UNSIGNED(L_LEFT downto 0) is L;
    alias XR: UNSIGNED(L_LEFT downto 0) is R;
    variable RESULT: UNSIGNED(L_LEFT downto 0);
    variable CBIT: STD_LOGIC := C;
  begin
    for I in 0 to L_LEFT loop
      RESULT(I) := CBIT xor XL(I) xor XR(I);
      CBIT := (CBIT and XL(I)) or (CBIT and XR(I)) or (XL(I) and XR(I));
    end loop;
    return RESULT;
  end ADD_UNSIGNED;
```

The `RESULT`'s length is that of the L argument which is the same of both arguments to `UNSIGNED_ADD`.  There is no carry out implied in the result.

As in your case the result, assigned to `z` can be 8 bits.

Fix the comment delimiters in the port declarations, add a use clause to access package numeric_std, fix a '-' that should be a '.', spelling of `architecture` and add a test bench adding values for `a` and `b` set to all '1's and you can analyze, elaborate and run your design without error, telling you there isn't an array length error executing.

To get that ninth 'bit' as an output of the adder you can `RESIZE` one of your arguments to `+` to 9 bits or concatenate one argument with leading zeros to make a 9 bit value:

```
    z <= "0" & a + b;
```

It'll demonstrate that the 9th bit is needed for an accurate result:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity adder is
    port( 
        a: in  unsigned (7 downto 0);
        b: in  unsigned (4 downto 0); 
        z: out unsigned (8 downto 0)
    ); 
end adder;

architecture add of adder is 
begin 
    z <= "0" & a + b;
end architecture;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity tb_adder is 
end entity;

architecture foo of tb_adder is
    signal a: unsigned (7 downto 0) := (others => '1');
    signal b: unsigned (4 downto 0) := (others => '1');
    signal z: unsigned (8 downto 0);

    function unsigned_image(inp: unsigned) return string is
        variable image_str: string (1 to inp'length);
        alias input_str:  unsigned (1 to inp'length) is inp;
    begin
        for i in input_str'range loop
            image_str(i) := character'VALUE(std_ulogic'IMAGE(input_str(i)));
        end loop;
        return image_str;
    end;

begin

DUT: 
    entity work.adder
        port map (
            a => a,
            b => b,
            z => z
        );

MONITOR:
    process 
    begin
        wait for 1 ns;
        report "z = " & unsigned_image(z);
        wait;
    end process;

end architecture;
```

> david_koontz@Macbook: ghdl -a adder.vhdl
>   david_koontz@Macbook: ghdl -e tb_adder
>   david_koontz@Macbook: ghdl -r tb_adder
>   adder.vhdl:54:9:@1ns:(report note): z = 100011110

Comment: This is one reason that VHDL bothers me so much.  Your function unsigned_image is pretty complicated, and all it's doing is printing out an unsigned(8 downto 0).  It's frustrating to me, as it complicates your answer more than actually answering his original question.

Comment: @Russell, but numeric_std defines procedure to_string(), certainly this could be used instead?

Comment: rick - to_string available only in -2008.  @Russell "...VHDL bothers me so much" doesn't leave much room for reasoning. The function has one sequential statement plus declarations. Has both IMAGE and VALUE attributes and requires qualified expressions. Stackoverflow is about detailed answers to practical questions. "It's frustrating to me" seems a bit out of place. The test bench is a supporting proof for the premise the 9th bit is required. VHDL is also used for formal proofs. Mathematical operators have their ordinary meaning, which isn't covered in the standard.

Answer (score 0):

Other than this correction:

```
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
```

Your code is fine.

Additionally, adding an 8 bit number and a 5 bit number produces a 9 bit number, because you can overflow. For example, `"11111111" + "11111"` overflows a 8 bit output, but doesn't overflow a 9 bit output.

Comment: Ohh i thougt in an adder that a,b and z must be the same word length for it to work. But that is not the case then or?

Comment: The specification explicitly allows the arguments to have different sizes.